# how can i add the repeater field in buddy press user edit profile

Tags: buddypress

i want to add the repeater field in buddy press user edit profile.
where user can add the multiple injury date.so is there any way to do this..?
[image: see the demo image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try using BuddyPress Profile Pro plugin. It allows you to add repeater fields and groups pretty easily. Follow these steps:

1. [Download](https://wbcomdesigns.com/downloads/buddypress-profile-pro/) and install the plugin.
2. Now, you have to create a repeater group. Head to **Group Setting**
   tab.
3. Enter **Group Title** and **Group Description**. Check the boxes for
   the options **Display Group at Buddypress Profile** and
   **Repeater**.
4. Click on **Add** button.
5. Now, you have to add fields inside groups. Head to **Field Setting**
   tab. Enter **Field Title**, **Field Type** and **Field Group**.
   Check the boxes for the options **Display** and **Required**.
6. Finally, click on **Add** button.